# valid approach for website with multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out a valid approach to build my first, simple app with rails. It's kind of portfolio app with several sites like homepage, gallery, services, contact, privacy policy, etc.

What i want to achieve is to be able to modify almost every text area of each site from admin panel, so i assume that i need to have some place to store that data.

My attempt is to:

1. Create pages and sections model/controller, then setting one to many relation between them. From admin menu i can manage pages and sections.
2. Create public controller, which show action is public accessible and looks like

   ```
   @page = Page.where(permalink: params[:permalink]).first
   redirect_to action: 'index' if @page.nil?
   ```
3. Setting routes to get permalink from url to `Public#show`.
4. In show view i'm displaying each section of page.

This is doing fine, but in this approach sections have to contain entire HTML, therefore they are vulnerable to accidental structure damage while editing their content. I want to be able to modify only plain text, not entire html.

Also in my app i can't use different templates for each page because every route leads to show action.

I was trying to add methods to Pages controller corresponding to each page (home, contact, etc.). I gain access to templates but i'm loosing flexibility. No more permalink routes, no adding new pages.

Basically, I'm asking what is proper approach to building app with multiple, editable pages, which needs permalinks, templates and methods)? How to build database? Which models and controllers to use? How rails app structure should look like?

Comment: Building a fully-featured CMS as your first ever project in a new framework or language inadvisable.

Comment: I've been trying to get it working but i suppose you're right. It's too advanced as beginning project, so i decided to do simpler project. I will expand it when i'll be ready :D